# How should I format a large value array in latex?

Tags: arrays, tabularray

Hi I am trying to describe a value array I used in my program in my bachelor thesis report.
I thought it would look more in sync in latex but it does look weird.

Do you have any advice on how to format an array of values like this:

```
\documentclass
$$
    \left\{
    \begin{align}
    n_{keepers},\\
    n_{defenders},\\
    n_{defenders},\\
    n_{defenders},\\
    n_{defenders},\\
    n_{midfielders},\\
    n_{midfielders},\\
    n_{midfielders},\\
    n_{midfielders},\\
    n_{attackers},\\
    n_{attackers} \end{align}
    \right\}
$$

\end{document}
```

Should I use a table instead?

Edit: what I see:
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: @JamesT thank you, I am trying to render it nicely but I am failing with doing what I do on StackOverflow and mathexchange how to display mathjax here?

Comment: That is fine about the rendering, you have taken my comment too literally though, I meant your document class you are using in your document and any packages/commands you are using that are relevant, your code cannot be copy and pasted and compiled as it is, could you edit it to make it compile please?

Comment: never use the default math font for words `midfielders` is set as a product of 1-letter variables. use `\mathrm{midfielders}`  or `\mathit{midfielders}`  also do not ignore error messages, you can not use `align` in that context. The pdf is not intended to be usable after any error , just a dbugging aid

Comment: @JamesT Oh, thank you, I am actually using typora and then just export via pandoc as I use very little latex.

Comment: mathjax is not enabled on this site, use an image to show typeset output

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you so much, `\mathrm{n_defenders},` looks much nicer, with typora I only use `$$` like in mathjax.

Comment: JamesT and @DavidCarlisle, I added a screenshot.

Comment: you would not get the output you show from any standard font setup, where is the math italic?  But as you have not posted code that produces any output it's hard to debug that

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this does actually work (see my screenshot), your answer works too, but the \[ and \] are giving errors in Typora (typora.io), but other than that it looks really nice

Comment: No system using latex would let you put `\left..\right`  around `align` (whch makes full width equations with equation numbers) But as you have not shown any code and apparently are not using tex, it's quite possible you get the output you show from something

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, I thought I have made it clear in the comments above that I am using other tools with mathjax, in particular this works with typora, obsidian and notion. 
I later usually use pandoc to export it to a normal latex file which also renders correctly, the semantics of it I don't know. Sorry for that and also for not being as clear.

Comment: @user199590 it was clear It's just mostly off topic here as it doesn't use tex. I'm surprised mathjax allows braces around align, probably by accident not design. The fact that it allows align in `$$` is by design and a documented difference from latex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this, although normally without the commas
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{Bmatrix}
    n_{\mathrm{keepers}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{defenders}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{defenders}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{defenders}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{defenders}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{midfielders}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{midfielders}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{midfielders}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{midfielders}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{attackers}},\\
    n_{\mathrm{attackers}}
   \end{Bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Never use the default math font for words `midfielders` is set as a product of 1-letter variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks quite splendid!

Comment: Some suggestions. A) If the variables with same names are the same, discard them. If not, distinguish them. B) Short is beautiful. E.g. favor n_a4 over n_attacker_4 or similar and explain in running text, that n_a denotes the number of attackers etc.

Comment: @MS-SPO I see, I considered making it shorter, but I am using this as a parallel cartesian set description of action spaces I use in my reinforcement learning implementation, I think I should be as clear as possible even if it is a little ugly, such that people can reproduce my work